# Placement of 2 images as the background on one body

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

Dear visitors stackoverflow!

I can not solve a simple problem:
Body given the background of the picture **"1.jpg"** (it is automatically pressed against the header), 
I still need to put a picture - **"2.jpg"** to be pressed on the contrary to the footer. That is, I need some "rubber layout" in height, so that images were sliding when the height of the page is large, and would come when the content is not enough. I would be happy to link a working example (not even a demo, but just a site that I myself look the source code), but at least I would be grateful for the usual suggestions and ideas! Thank you in advance.

Sorry for bad English, I tried to write competently.

**update:**

> Thank you very much for your answers. Do not pay attention to what I
>   chose only one, you helped me and I thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full browser support, I'd have one image set on the `<body>`, and then another image set on a site container, e.g. `<div id="site">`

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title!</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="site">
    [Your website here]
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {background: url(img/image-1.jpg) top no-repeat;}
#site {background: url(img/image-2.jpg) bottom no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put you image 1.jpg in body background using css and 2.jpg in background of footer.

I dont know what are the sizes of your images so You can see the below link to get some help -

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with CSS3:

```
body {
    background: url("1.jpg") top left,
        url("2.jpg") bottom right;
}
```

If you require support for older browsers ([See here for current support](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20background)), you will have to use an  tag for the second image.

Comment: @user1103744 you're quite welcome. Once you have verified that this helps you, please mark the post as accepted by clicking the green tick.